# How to find if two or more continuously elements of a vector are equal in R

Tags: r, vector, element, equals

I want to find a way to determine if two or more continuously elements of a vector are equal.

For example, in vector `x=c(1,1,1,2,3,1,3)`, the first, the second and the third element are equal.

With the following command, I can determine if a vector, say `y`, contains two or more continuously elements that are equal to `2` or `3`

```
all(rle(y)$lengths[which( rle(y)$values==2 | rle(y)$values==3 )]==1)
```

Is there any other faster way?

EDIT

Let say we have the vector `z=c(1,1,2,1,2,2,3,2,3,3)`.
I want a vector with three elements as output. The first element will refer to value `1`, the second to `2` and the third one to `3`. The values of the elements of the output vector will be equal to `1` if two or more continuously elements of `z` are the same for one value of `1,2,3` and `0` otherwise. So, the output for the vector `z` will be `(1,1,1)`.

For the vector `w=c(1,1,2,3,2,3,1)` the output will be `1,0,0`, since only for the value `1` there are two continuously elements, that is in the first and in the second position of `w`.

Comment: please add a practical example and expected outcome !

Comment: @Darren I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if I'm understanding your question as it could be worded better. The first part just asks how you find if continuous elements in a vector are equal. The answer is to use the `diff()` function combined with a check for a difference of zero:

```
z <- c(1,1,2,1,2,2,3,2,3,3)
sort(unique(z[which(diff(z) == 0)]))
# [1] 1 2 3

w <- c(1,1,2,3,2,3,1) 
sort(unique(w[which(diff(w) == 0)]))
# [1] 1
```

But your edit example seems to imply you are looking to see if there are repeated units in a vector, of which will only be the integers 1, 2, or 3. Your output will always be X, Y, Z, where

X is 1 if there is at least one "1" repeated, else 0

Y is 2 if there is at least one "2" repeated, else 0

Z is 3 if there is at least one "3" repeated, else 0

Is this correct?

If so, see the following

```
continuously <- function(x){
  s <- sort(unique(x[which(diff(x) == 0)]))
  output <- c(0,0,0)
  output[s] <- s
  return(output)
}

continuously(z)
# [1] 1 2 3
continuously(w)
# [1] 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your series name is `z=c(1,1,2,1,2,2,3,2,3,3)` then you can do:

`(unique(z[c(FALSE, diff(z) == 0)]) >= 0)+0` which will output to `1, 1, 1`,

When you run the above command on your other sequenc:

```
w=c(1,1,2,3,2,3,1)
```

then `(unique(w[c(FALSE, diff(w) == 0)]) >= 0)+0` will return to `1`

You may also try this for an exact output like 1,1,1 or 1,0,0

```
(unique(z[c(FALSE, diff(z) == 0)]) == unique(z))+0 #1,1,1 for z and 1,0,0 for w
```

**Logic:**

`diff` command will take difference between corresponding second and prior items, since total differences will always 1 less than the number of items, I have added first item as FALSE. Then subsetted with your original sequences and for boolean comparison whether the difference returned is zero or not. Finally we convert them to 1s by asking if they are greater than or equal to 0 (To get series of 1s, you may also check it with some other conditions to get 1s).

Assuming your sequence doesn't have negative numbers.